# Cardinality of the following sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

[Cardinality of set question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YRJg.png)

Please Correct if I am wrong at any point since at some points I must go wrong in my basic understanding of the question and data.

My understanding of this is that set A={1,2,3..,n} refers to a set, A, having n number of natural numbers in order for example if n=5 A={1,2,3,4,5} and if n=10 A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}. The Cardinality of a set is the number of elements in the set for example if n=5 set A has a cardinality of 5 and etc.

For the question itself my understanding is that they've defined a set {a,S} such that, a, is a member of, S, and, S, is a member of the power set of, A, and I'm supposed to find the number of elements in this set. My current understanding is: The Cardinality of P(A) is 2^n. S, is a member of P(A) so therefore should have the same cardinality and, a, is a member of, S, and so should have the same cardinality making the overall set have a cardinality of 2^2n.

However this answer is completely wrong, the answer says that there a n choices for a and 2^(n-1) choices for S since we can choose the set of S \ {a} in 2^(n-1) ways giving us the answer of n2^(n-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Consider instead $\{(a,T)~:~a\in A,~a\notin T,~T\in\mathcal{P}(A)\}$

See if you can come up with a bijection from that set to yours

> $(a,T)\mapsto (a,T\cup \{a\})$

Now, as for counting the size of this set, break apart via multiplication principle.  First pick the element $a$.  Then, pick a subset not containing $a$.

> $n\cdot 2^{n-1}$

Comment: I understand you're set and how it gets to n*n^(n-1), thank you very much and it's actually the next question of this exercise but I don't understand how you relate your set to mine, apologies if this in a stupid question but how does 'or-ing' a set of ,a, into the pair turn it into the set I have? If the pair (a,T)={{a},{a,T}} then isn't { {a}, {a,T} } U {a} the same as (a,T)?

Comment: Breaking down what you just said... yes, formally an ordered pair can be thought of as a two element set like you write... but I would just as soon sweep that under the rug for now as it looks like it is just serving to confuse you.  It is a tuple, and we don't normally talk about performing a union with a tuple.  Next, I had said to union $T$ with $\{a\}$, not the tuple with $\{a\}$.  Finally, even if we *were* to union the tuple with $\{a\}$, the result would be $\{a,\{a\},\{a,T\}\}$, a three element set, not a two-element set, and so not equal.

Comment: As an example, suppose $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  One of the pairs in my collection of pairs would be something like $(1,\{2,3,4\})$.  This corresponds to the pair $(1,\{1,2,3,4\})$ in the original question's set of pairs.  All I did was include the element into the subset that it is paired with.

Comment: ah ok so (a,T) could become (1,{2,3,4}) pair but if you biject {a} with T then you get (1,{1,2,3,4}) which you can rewrite as (a,S) where ,a,=,a, and S=T U {a} and ,a, becomes a member of S and S remains a member of P(A). They still have the same cardinality because {a} a duplicate right? like how {1,1,2,3}={1,2,3}? Thank you for the quick responses so far as well!

Comment: "*They still have the same cardinality because $\{a\}$ a duplicate right?*"  I don't get what you mean by that.  We are asking how many possible pairs we have.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that $A$ has $2^n$ subsets. Now think about how you can write a pair $(a,S)$ as required.

There are $n$ ways to pick $a$. Once you have $a$, how many ways are there to choose a subset $S$ that contains $a$? That's just deciding which of the other $n-1$ elements of $A$ belong.

Comment: Am I right in saying that if n=3 A={1,2,3} and P(A)={null,{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3}} and that S is equal to one of those sets (either null or {1} or {2} all the way to {1,2,3}) and so ,a, is equal to one of those values within the subset. For example if S={2,3} then ,a, is either 2 or 3?

Comment: @AdamG yes, if you decide to pick $S$ before having picked $a$.  Yes, $(2,\{2,3\})$ and $(3,\{2,3\})$ are both pairs included in your collection.  The trick for counting this effectively however is to *not* have picked $S$ first, but rather to have picked $a$ first.

Comment: So you're able to pick ,a, first because it can only be of the values in the original A set right? Secondly once ,a, is chosen can S only be a subset without ,a, within it?